# How to remove/modify syslogd message's header?

Tags: linux, logging, syslog, busybox

I'm currently use the syslogd of busybox for logging some information. However, I'm unable to modify the message's header.
I log the message like this:

```
syslog(LOG_INFO,"My message\n");
```

And I got this output:

```
Jul  4 15:00:11 halo user.info syslog: My message
```

I want to **replace** message's header with epoch time format like this:

```
1529293692,My message
```

Or is there any way to **completely remove** the message's header so I could manually add the epoch time in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done the research around and found that it is impossible to modify the output message log of syslogd with supported configuration. So I dig into the busybox's source code and modify it. If you face the same issue, you could find it at function:

```
static void timestamp_and_log(int pri, char *msg, int len)
```

I check the **pri** variable to see which level log is it and change the actual outcome message, which is **msg**.